# how to change div's class which is inside datalist code behind

Tags: asp.net, html, datalist

I want to change `div` class which is inside the datalist code behind. If the `div` is not inside the datalist it is okay but it is inside datalist at prsent. My code is

```
<asp:DataList ID="datalistsorular" runat="server" 
        BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Width="730px">
        <ItemTemplate>
<div class="divsorugoruntulenmesayisi" id="cevaplanma" runat="server">
                <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Cevaplanma_Sayisi") %>'></asp:Label>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

if is not inside datalist I would do code behind but datalist raise an issue in this case.

```
cevaplanma.Attributes["class"] = "otherclass";
```

Comment: What Issue you are getting?

Comment: At which time you want to do such operation? in ItemDataBound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this control is inside the item template, you will not get this by using the id simply, as it will not be unique.
You need to handle it in event handler.

```
<asp:DataList ID="datalistsorular" runat="server" 
    BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Width="730px" onitemdatabound="datalistsorular_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <div class="divsorugoruntulenmesayisi" id="cevaplanma" clientIDMode="static" runat="server">
      <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Cevaplanma_Sayisi") %>'>              
      </asp:Label>
      </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

And your code behind should look like:.

```
protected void datalistsorular_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
       //Find control and apply the class..
       // something like e.Item.FindControl("cevaplanma")
       HtmlControl div = e.Item.FindControl("cevaplanma") as HtmlControl;
       if (div != null)
       {
        div.Attributes["class"] = "className";
       }
}
```

You need to add the line:

```
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
```

Comment: Okay but I dont know how I do this

Comment: On which condition you want to change the class of your div "cevaplanma" ?

Comment: foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                int aswercount = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Cevaplanma_Sayisi"]);
                if (aswercount > 0)
                {
                    //change div's class
                }
            }

Comment: `dr.FindControl("cevaplanma").Attributes["class"]="anotherClass"`

Answer (score 0):

After you bind the data to this dataList, each row in the dataSource will have this div. You need to find the corresponding row and set the class

```
((System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl)(datalistsorular.Items[rowIndex].FindControl("cevaplanma"))).Attributes["class"]="anotherClass"
```